# why the contour of the circle is not uniform

Tags: c++, graphics, sfml

I need to write c++ code that outputs a circle using sfml. but every time I face a problem, the contour of the circle is not uniform, but jagged

This is my cod:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    // Window size
    const int windowSize = 800;

    // Create window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(windowSize, windowSize), "Drawing a Circle using Sine and Cosine");

    // Circle radius
    float radius = 100.0f;

    // Center of the window
    float centerX = windowSize / 2.0f;
    float centerY = windowSize / 2.0f;

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // Event handling
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        // Clear the window
        window.clear();

        // Drawing the circle
        sf::VertexArray circle(sf::LineStrip, 361); // 361 vertices for each degree

        // Set the position of the vertices based on sine and cosine values
        for (int theta = 0; theta <= 360; ++theta)
        {
            float x = centerX + radius * std::cos(theta * (3.14159 / 180.0f));
            float y = centerY + radius * std::sin(theta * (3.14159 / 180.0f));
            circle[theta].position = sf::Vector2f(x, y);
        }

        // Display the circle
        window.draw(circle);

        // Display the result
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I expect that the resulting circle will have a uniform contour, as with the smoothing effect

Comment: *"as with the smoothing effect"* -- What smoothing effect?

Comment: Just tossing some numbers out here. Your radius is 100. Each quarter-circle extends 100 (units) vertically and horizontally, making the curve longer than 100 (whatever the units are). This curve is rendered using 91 points. Is it okay that the curve has fewer points than units of length?

Comment: What do you mean with smooth? Do you mean you still see some line segments or do you mean the circle is not anti-aliased?

Comment: Not sure what do you think is wrong with your circle. I tried to reproduce, and it looks round, and quite smooth, considering that it's composed of single points. Can you post a picture of your result and point what's wrong?